# Optimizing use of C# events?

Tags: c#, events, optimization

I have a game in which players connect and see a list of challenges. In the code, challenges are stored in a dictionary by their status so I have a `Dictionary<string, List<Challenge>>` to store them.

I have a class that handles all related challenges actions, such as retrieving them from a server, and this class sends events to notify interested objects about the update. My problem is my delegate for the event is sending the whole dictionary and I'm realizing this is probably very bad in terms of garbage created or even execution speed.

My app will run on mobile and I'm working on Unity so I'm limited to .Net 3.5 (some 4 features). Performance is critical here so I would like to know what would be a more efficient way of doing this ?

The only thing I see right away would be to remove the dictionary from the event delegate and just access my singleton's instance variable instead of having it as a parameter. But I want to be sure there is no better way and that this will indeed be more efficient.

Comment: Surely you are only really passing a reference to the dictionary, since the dictionary is a reference type. You're not making a clone of the dictionary before passing it are you?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was worried some internals would have to create temporary copies or something like that but apparently there is no such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are [*reference types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a class, therefore, you're not copying the dictionary but just pointing to the same one from different references (for example, the event args providing a reference to the so-called dictionary).

If you're very worried about memory issues with event handlers, you can take a look at [*weak event pattern*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970850(v=vs.100).aspx), which can led to prevent some memory leaks in some use cases (but you'll need .NET 4.0 at least...).

Comment: Yes so no overhead from passing it around and this is consistent with the results I get from the profiler.

Comment: @GeoffreyHug I'm glad to know you could arrive to some conclusion ;)